# Add additional angular libraries at runtime (not declared as routes)

Tags: angular, dynamic, lazy-loading

Do you know if there is a way to dynamically add routes & libraries **at run-time** for an angular app ?
Even with lazy loading mechanism, all the routes **must be defined in a typescript routing file** (so that angular compiler can generate chunks at build-time). I didn't find a way for an app, to load additional routes and libraries on demand at runtime.

The idea behind that, is that whenever an angular app starts, it looks inside a json file for the libraries it should load. It then dynamically populates the router with those routes and associates a module to lazy-load when the user will click on a route. By doing that, we could add some new features to an app, without having to rebuild it.

Any ideas ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question if it can help someone else.
I think the right way to go nowadays is to use Microfrontends and compose a shell app with many UI sub-apps.
Angular supports this officially with the architecture module.

Comment: I don't know if this two links:[Loading External Libraries on Demand](https://netbasal.com/loading-external-libraries-on-demand-in-angular-9dad45701801) and [Lazy Load Non-Routable Modules](https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093) can help you

Comment: any resource to share about this finding ?